# How do I update 'x' correctly?

Tags: python, direction

So I'm working on a game, and here is my current code, which works fine:

```
print("Type directions() to see commands" )

def directions() :

    print("Type North, East, South or West to move" )
    move = input("North, East, South or West? ")
    if move == "North":
    north()
    elif move == "East":
    east()
    elif move == "South":
    south()
    elif move == "West":
    west()


def north():
    print("You moved North")
    x=0
    x=(x+1) 
    print("You are at co-ordinates", x, "x:0 y" )
```

However, I am aware that later there will be a problem as x would be reset for each direction. When putting `x=0` at the top of the code and removing it from the `def north()` part, when running the code, Python gives me the error:

> 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment'

How can I code this so that 'x' is 0 to begin with, but can be altered by `def` functions?

Comment: You could make ```x``` global.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) for one way to do this using global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of 2 things: either use a global variable (which should be mostly avoided), or use return values. The global method:

```
x=0
.
.
def directions():
    .
    .
def north():
    global x
    x=x+1
    print("moved north...")
```

or, the return value:

```
def directions():
    current_location = 0
    .
    .
    if move == "North":
         current_location = North(current_location)
    .
    .
def North(location):
    print("moved north...")
    return location+1
```

Judging by your question and the existence of `y`, you can do the following:

```
def directions():
.
.
    if move == "North":
        (x,y) = North(x,y)
.
.
def North(x,y):
    return (x+1,y)
def East(x,y):
    return (x,y+1)
def South(x,y):
    return (x-1,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tips (not exhaustive, but enough for a start):

First, use a global dictionary for your directions:

```
def north(x):
    return x+1

directions = {'North': north, 'East': east, 'South': south, 'West': west}
def move(x) :
    global directions
    print("Type North, East, South or West to move")
    move_choice = input("North, East, South or West? ")
    # modify lambda to your logic to handle incorrect inputs
    x = directions.get(move, lambda y:y)(x)
    repr(x)
    return x
```

and if you want functional approach (as opposed to OOP), your functions has to accept some arguments:

```
def north(x):
    return x+1
```

Don't mix your logic and representation, this way you'll have to copy alot of code:

```
def repr(x):
    print("You are at co-ordinates {} x:0 y".format(x))
```

and combine them in `main` routine:

```
def main():
    x = 0
    while True: # modify to be able to terminate this loop
        x = move(x)
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work using the Micromoses' comment, but thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what Cygwinnian suggested, making `x` a global variable will fix the problem. That means the same `x` variable is accessible from all functions which declare `global x`before they use `x`.

To fix your error:

```
x = 0

print("Type directions() to see commands" )

def directions() :
    print("Type North, East, South or West to move" )
    move = input("North, East, South or West? ")
    if move == "North":
    north()
    elif move == "East":
    east()
    elif move == "South":
    south()
    elif move == "West":
    west()


def north():
    global x
    print("You moved North")
    x=(x+1) 
    print("You are at co-ordinates", x, "x:0 y" )
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work using the Micromoses' comment, but thank you for the help :)